# Bias location returns on Google Places API autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api

I am using the Google places API to autocomplete street address searches. I want to bias the results to a 50 mile radius around a specific longitude and latitude (this is a fixed location, it doesn't depend on the user). Currently, it autocompletes addresses, but it doesn't bias them based on location (other than doing within the U.S.). Specifically, I want to bias a 300 mile radius around latitude: 34.159947, longitude: -118.257017.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        ...
<input id="address-search" type="text" value="" name="subject">


$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('address-input');
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'} };               
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't give it a radius, but you can give it rectangular bounds

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631)
);

var options = {bounds: defaultBounds };
```

See the [Places Autocomplete documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks. There's an extra parenthesis btw on line 4